# How to gracefully handle missing translation files when using AngularJS static file loader?

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

If you have multiple rules in your `useStaticFilesLoader` definition and  one of them is a folder that is missing, angular translate will fail even if the translations contained in the missing files are not used.

For instance I replaced the the actual `prompts` folder name with the wrong `foo` name. If you restore the correct folder name everything works fine.

```
$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
    files: [{
      prefix: 'lang_',
      suffix: '.json'
    }, {
      prefix: 'foo/lang_',
      suffix: '.json'
    }]
  });
```

[Plunk example](https://embed.plnkr.co/ShhiUlX1NCKYENIds59N/)

Is there a way to ignore a missing file and keep using the other files?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to use a [custom loader](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/13_custom-loaders) instead of the standard static loader.

```
app.factory('translationLoader', function ($q, $http) {
  return function (options) {
    var deferred = $q.defer(),
      translations;

    $http.get('lang_' options.key + '.json')
      .then(function (res) {
        translations = res.data;

        $http.get('subfolder/lang_' + options.key + '.json')
          .then(function (res) {
            translations = translations.concat(res.data);
          }, function () {
            deferred.resolve(translations);
          })
          .finally(function () {
            deferred.resolve(translations);
          });
      }, function () {
        deferred.reject(options.key);
      });

    return deferred.promise;
  };
})
.config([
  '$translateProvider',
  function ($translateProvider) {
    $translateProvider
      .useSanitizeValueStrategy(null)
      .useLoader('translationLoader');
  }
]);
```